# Opencart track external links

Tags: hyperlink, module, opencart, external, tracking

I am trying to find a way or a module for Opencart (1.5.6 xx) so I can track external links.

On a page link name is: www.example.com and the URL something like www.mywebsite.com/redir/a2df6y89

Any help or directions would be fantabulous.
Thanx

Answer (score 0):

why not use [google analytic's](http://analytics.google.com) or [google tag manager](https://www.google.co.za/analytics/tag-manager/). I know they are the best and are really accurate to track tags. Easy to use and it's google.